# How to do JS pre-processing with Uglifier and assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs

What I'm trying to do (and I'm not sure is possible) is to use UglifierJS to pre-process the JS files using its AST 'mangle' options object. There's an option {defines: {**DEVMODE**: true}} that you can pass to UglifyJS: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#use-as-a-code-pre-processor

The Uglify GEM that works with Rails basically uses the same, "defines" is not supposed to be part of the GEM implementation, but I hard-coded it to change a couple of lines of the gem so it will included as one more option.

In any case, the point is how can I use the pre-processing approach in development, so the assets pipeline delivers JS files in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added support for defines to Uglifier. It's not released yet, but you can use by depending on latest version on git.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'uglifier', :git => 'https://github.com/lautis/uglifier.git'
```

Instantiate Uglifier with used defines, e.g.

```
Uglifier.new(:define => {"DEVMODE" => true})
```

Alternatively, when using asset pipeline you could use erb preprocessor together with your JS code. Name your file something.js.erb and write code like

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  console.log(debug)
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Lautis . While the ERB is an excellent approach, is there a way to use Uglifier within the assets pipeline with only the `:define` option to preprocess the JS output in development? (may) be faster and prettier :)

Comment: You could enable compression in dev env and set up Uglifier to not really compress JS (mangle: false, squeeze: false). It'll still be quire slow.

I'd probably have a env.js.erb where DEVMODE and similar constants are set up. You could use Uglifier to set these values in production and omit logging code entirely in deployed assets.

Comment: nice. Thanks for the great advice again!